# PromptOptions dialog doesn't appear in embeded bot framework web chat

Tags: botframework

I have a bot framework v4 bot that prompts the user for a set of options using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.PromptOptions.
In Skype for business I see a list of options and I have to type back the chosen answer. In the "Test in Web Chat" section in Azure, I see buttons for the options as well as in the Bot Framework Emulator. 
But when I use the iframe to embed the chat, if at the top of the conversation appears a welcome message and the bot icon, then the buttons don't display, neither the written options. But sometimes that Welcome message doesn't appear when the chat loads, and at that moment the buttons do appear.

The PromptOptions dialog is triggered by the first message of a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two versions of Web Chat you need to be aware of - Web Chat and Bot Chat. Bot Chat renders prompt options as a list while Web Chat creates buttons for each option. Currently, the iFrame renders a Bot Chat component, and the Emulator uses Web Chat which is why your prompt options are rendering as buttons in the Emulator and not in the iFrame.

The BotFramework development team is planning to upgrade the iFrame from Bot Chat to Web Chat in the next release, which should be relatively soon. You can either wait for the update or add Web Chat directly to your app.

For more information on embedding Web Chat in your site, take a look a the [Web Chat Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input. The weird thing is that when the welcome section doesn't get displayed, I'm assuming because of an error, the options were displayed as buttons.
Anyway, now I always see the welcome message and don't see the options, not as buttons nor as a list.